# Power supply board

Tags: power-supply, power, board

[image]
I am wondering what the component that looks like a fire cracker is in this picture. It feels like paper or possibly ceramic on the outside. There are no markings.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to say for certain without inspecting the board directly, but it's probably a resistor. Long, thin packages like that are sometimes used for high-value (MΩ - GΩ) resistors, especially ones which may be subjected to high voltages.

[image]

Here's another similar modern part -- it's a 10 GΩ resistor, rated for 10 kV!

Comment: Is there any way to tell what the resistor in the board is or what I should replace it with? The fuses in the board are all 250v 1A. No board schematics exist.

Answer (score 3):

Your component has been hot .The PCB underneath shows this .The part could be a reasistor that did have markings that have burnt off over the decades.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f97fnt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Judging by the location of the Cathodes it appears to be a 10A diode bridge with a power resistor to bleed the stored energy in the cap when powered off.

THe other advantage of this is a preload voltage limit on peak diode cap voltage to reduce the dynamic range of unregulated output from -50 to -25% say

Meaning if the no load and no R1, DC out rises 50% to peak sine + conduction loss I^R  and full load drops 50% thus R1 acts as a PRELOAD to reduce Vdc by ~20% roughly by design.  If you are getting DC out, this part is not your problem and it should be warm. It no output, look elsewhere for a short or open fuse.

Comment: Thank you all. Is there any way to tell what to replace it with? There are no schematics around any more.

Comment: Why do you think it is bad?   probably 300 Ohms +/-50% guess  assume 1~2 watts max dissipation and use Vdc^/1W=R  and choose wirewound 5W part.

Comment: Because it looks like it had a blow out. All the burn marks and gray soot on the board came from it.

Comment: then its an old carbon composition part. possibly failed from over voltage and no load.